# Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

Tags: javascript

Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object

I want to insert every class which match the color propery to an array.Then, show the array on console log.

I get error.What is the problem?

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    "use strict"

```
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(node) {
    const style = window.getComputedStyle(node);
    const color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
    const Bcolor = style.getPropertyValue('background-color');


    if (color === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {
     const nodelistToArray = Array.apply(null, node.className);
       console.log( nodelistToArray);


        $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
            node.style.setProperty("color", "red", "important");
            return false;
        });

        $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
            node.style.setProperty("color", "pink", "important");
            return false;
        });

    }

        if (Bcolor === 'rgb(22, 160, 133)') {

        $("ul.colors .color1").on('click', function() {
            node.style.setProperty("background-color", "red", "important");
            return false;
        });

        $("ul.colors .color2").on('click', function() {
            node.style.setProperty("backgroundColor", "pink", "important");
            return false;
        });

    }


});

    $("#color-style-switcher .bottom a.settings").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var div = $("#color-style-switcher");
        if (div.css("left") === "-195px") {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "0px"
            });
        } else {
            $("#color-style-switcher").animate({
                left: "-195px"
            });
        }
    })

    $("ul.colors li a").on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().parent().find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    })
```

});

Comment: I'm afraid your question is rather unclear to me at this time. Can you try to describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Why not use some variable to store those names? Why you want to use console.log for that?

Comment: @JayNyxed I want to use variable contains the classes as the form what I gave you that class space another class.But I am not good js syntax so I need your helps

Comment: @Jhecht want to use variable contains the classes as the form what I gave you that class space another class.But I am not good js syntax so I need your helps

Comment: Create something like `var arr = []` and where you now call your console log, just do `arr.push(className)`. All class names are gonna be stored in that array where you can access them.

Comment: after I added the class names to a array, how can I select the class names with customized settings by queryselector from the array? Simply, instead of seach in all page with queryselector, how can I search in that array?

Comment: I will add the class manuelly to array

Comment: You mean you want to receive the info about the class(like display, color, background-color) by its class name?

Comment: @JayNyxed I editted question.Can you look at again?

Comment: You should create your array variable outside of the forEach loop.
And I am not even sure what you are trying to do here: `const nodelistToArray = Array.apply(null, node.className);` Are you trying to add element to array? Then why not `push`?

Answer (score 0):

try saving the console.log in a variable like this

```
let consoleStyle = node.className;
```

and pass then to:

```
setAttribute('class', consoleStyle);
```

Comment: I didnt mean it.I want to save the class names to a js variable or call a file to add them to a js variable then use the variable instead of use * selector